# How can I have several javascript functions without having document.ready() for each one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have working code that includes:

```
  $(document).ready(function() 
  { $("#num1").click(function() { $("li.elementsA").addClass("alerty"); 
     return false }); });
  $(document).ready(function() 
  { $("#num2").click(function() { $("li.element").addClass("ok"); 
     return false }); });
```

How can I have both functions without the document.ready piece in the second one.

I tried

```
  $(document).ready(function() 
  { $("#num1").click(function() { $("li.elementsA").addClass("alerty"); 
    return false }); }
  { $("#num2").click(function() { $("li.element").addClass("ok"); 
    return false }); });
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: why do you want 2 functions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your 2nd example, the DOM Ready handler function is closed at the end of the 3rd line at the last `}`, after that you get a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`.

You just have to wrap both `click` handlers inside of the DOM ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#num1").click(function () {
        $("li.elementsA").addClass("alerty");
        return false;
    });
    $("#num2").click(function () {
        $("li.element").addClass("ok");
        return false;
    });
});
```

I [beautified](http://jsbeautifier.org/) your code to make it easier to read too. `=]`

Here are the non-beautified changes to make it "more" visible in relation to the original code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() 
  { $("#num1").click(function() { $("li.elementsA").addClass("alerty"); 
    return false });
//↓Remove { here     ↑And } here
    $("#num2").click(function() { $("li.element").addClass("ok"); 
    return false }); });
```

Comment: "Proper" indentation makes our life so much easier :D

Comment: Fully agreed @Andreas, added the link to jsbeautifier. `=]`